# Firebase analytics cloud triggers limits

Tags: firebase, cloud, google-cloud-functions, analytics, firebase-analytics

Currently i have more than 15 analytics events for which i need triggers to send messages to external services (e.g Slack).

Firebase analytics enforces a limit of 15 conversion events so my current use case is not possible to implement this way. Is the only alternative calling the cloud functions directly with the same event payload?

This looks to me like a ugly workaround.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The limit of 15 conversion events is a hard limit and can't be increased.

You have lots of options, but what you said might be the easiest.  You could also write to Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore and trigger a function that way as well.